# Default timestamp format and fractional seconds

Tags: postgresql, datetime, format, timestamp, default

I'm trying to format the timestamps in my Postgres database to a certain format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS
```

By doing:

```
update myTable set tds = to_char(tds, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')::timestamp;
```

I managed to set all the previously stored `tds` to this format. However, any newly added entry goes back to: `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS` since the default is set to `now()`.

How do I change this so that newly added entries also have the format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`?

Comment: I see that you want to truncat milliseconds part ? you can do it by using a trigger.

Comment: Where is your table definition? We'd need to see it to be sure. `\d myTable` in psql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no format stored in a timestamp type. You can set its default to a timestamp truncated to the second at creation time

```
create table t (
    tds timestamp default date_trunc('second', now())
)
```

Or alter the table

```
alter table t 
alter column tds 
set default date_trunc('second', now());

insert into t values (default);
INSERT 0 1

select * from t;
         tds         
---------------------
 2014-03-11 19:24:11
```

If you just don't want to show the milliseconds part format the output

```
select to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
       to_char       
---------------------
 2014-03-11 19:39:40
```

Answer (score 4):

The types [`timestamp` or `timestamptz`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) optionally take a precision modifier *`p`*: `timestamp(p)`.
To ***round*** to full seconds, set the default to:

```
now()::timestamp(0)
```

or:

```
now()::timestamptz(0)
```

Standard SQL functions [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) (returns `timestamptz`) or [`LOCALTIMESTAMP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) (returns `timestamp`) allow the same precision modifier:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)
LOCALTIMESTAMP(0)
```

That's a bit shorter than calling `date_trunc()` - which ***truncates*** fractional seconds (may be what you really want!)

```
date_trunc('second', now())
```

Store timestamps as `timestamptz` (or `timestamp`), *not* as character type.

Finally, to make **sure** that ...

> newly added entries also have the format: YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS

you *could* define your column as type `timestamptz(0)`. This covers all values entered into that column, not just the default. But the rounding may introduce timestamps up to half a second in the future. If that can be an issue in any way, rather use `date_trunc()`.

See [@Clodoaldo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22334647/939860) for instructions on [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) and how to [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html).

This related answer for in-depth information on timestamps and time zone handling:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)